# How to replace string contents of All Alpha buttons to empty and get them back on pressing Alt

Tags: prism-4

I want to make a virtual keyboard and want to disappear its all contents `[a-zA-Z]` and get them back on clicking Alt...
But my Problem is that I applied a replace function,As

[image]

these are working properly but I want to write something like this:

> fb.Content = (IsAltEnable ? fb.Content.ToString().Replace("[^a-zA-Z]",
>   "") : fb.Content.ToString().Replace("", "[^a-zA-Z]"));

but this is not working properly.

Comment: Plz copy your code instead of putting image!

Comment: I have sent it again...              http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33779494/i-want-to-replace-string-using-regex-and-i-want-to-replace-a-za-z-to-empty-an

Comment: Please Check my Question in this link... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33779494/i-want-to-replace-string-using-regex-and-i-want-to-replace-a-za-z-to-empty-an